# How to make options for each page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating Dynamic wordpress template to publish it on themeforest and other Marketplace and i want to add specific options for each page (NOT options page) this options will show and the bottom of Add new page .
i wanna ask what is the name of this function or how i can add options like in the photo

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, you need Meta Boxes and Custom Fields, check WP documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can research more on using wordpress [custom fields](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/), 
Here is a good tutorial https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/

Answer (score 0):

you can use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin for it. It is easy to create option for page, post, custom post using it and It has very good documentation.

here is the link :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/